# HTL conditional in styling

Tags: css, if-statement, conditional-statements, aem, sightly

`<div  style="${properties.position == 'bottom'? 'bottom: ${properties.HeightValue}' : ': unset' @ context='styleString'}">`

hello guys, I'm trying to add a condition inside of my AEM's inline style code, both values are existing.
I can only see the first condition, `${properties.position == 'bottom'` worked,
but `${properties.HeightValue}` is showing as string.

ON DOM, it's showing like this below:
`<div style="bottom: ${properties.HeightValue}">`

I tried some other method like but still did not work, wonder if you guys do know how to work this around.

i also tried this method, did not work as well:
`top: ${properties.position == 'bottom'? '${properties.HeightValue}' : '0''}` 
thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot nest expressions like that. What you could do is take out the fixed part and only leave the variables in the ternary:

```
<div style="bottom: ${properties.position == 'bottom' ? properties.HeightValue : 'unset' @ context='styleString'}">
```

Comment: it worked! it was pretty similar with my second try, but I did not thought of that. thank you!